# Run Python script as an exe without showing a command window

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am a security student first starting out with Python. I've built my first program for my class and it is meant to be an exe so that it may run on any computer without having me install python onto it. The program is meant to go unnoticed by the user, but whenever it is executed a command windows pops up.

Does anyone know how to make a .py into a .exe that when launched would not bring up the command prompt?

I have already tried compiling a .pyw into a .exe and it still pops up the command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried using a tray icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around the py2exe web site, you need to say `setup(windows=['myapp.pyw'])` instead of `setup(console=['myapp.py'])`.  I have problems finding out which page is saying that exactly, but hints are given here for example (search for "console"):

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ